# LDAP template search by multiple attributes

Tags: spring, spring-ldap

Trying to search for users details by using userid,emailid,firstname,lastname,GUID,etc...many more values that need to be added in future

The search should be performed using all the attributes which are not null.
Found this piece of code online *

> **String filter = "(&(sn=YourName)(mail=*))";**

*
Is there any other predefined template or such to do the search, more optimal way without directly specifying values to be Null or using if else statements for each and every attribute? All values must be passed to the method and those not null must be used for search using LDAP. Anything? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can effectively use the Filters at run time to specify what to use for search and what not depending on some rules or your NULL validations on attributes. Pls find sample code which fetches person name using filters in ldapTemplate :-

```
public static final String BASE_DN = "dc=xxx,dc=yyy";
private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate ;
public List getPersonNames() { 
    String cn = "phil more";
    String sn = "more";
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person"));
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("sn", sn));
    filter.and(new WhitespaceWildcardsFilter("cn", cn));
    return ldapTemplate.search(
       BASE_DN, 
       filter.encode(),
       new AttributesMapper() {
          public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs)
             throws NamingException {
             return attrs.get("cn").get();
          }
       });
 }
```

As name suggests the AndFilters joins all individual filters used in lookup like EqualFilter which checks for equality of attributes while WhitespaceWildcardsFilter to perform wildcard search. So here like we got cn = phil more, it in turn uses `*phil*more*` for search.

Comment: Thanks Avis...AND Filter was just what i needed